# PIL ImageDraw.Text or ImageDraw.multiline_text Alignment

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library, text-alignment

I want to draw a price into a picture with fontsize=2x vor the dollars and fontsize=x for the cents, like this:
[image: different price tags for showing what i want]

---

I want to be able to write 1.90 and 19.90 and so on, which is why I want the dollars amount to be right aligned, while the cents amount is of standard left alignment.

Edit: I forgot a vital point: The comma is fixed (because of a display position) and I want to write the dollars value so that it expands to the left, while the cent value always stays as is (00, 05, 10, 19, 99....). So when instead of 12,99 I write for example 123,99 I still want the , to be in the same position. My only Idea so far was to work with single chars, which are less comfortable to handle :(

Comment: Can you tell us what you've tried and how it fails to work?  It seems to me that by changing the fonts  and using the `textsize` function in the `ImageDraw module`, it would be straightforward to achieve what you want, but I haven't tried it myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the ImageDraw module, you can get the size of a text string.

```
draw.textsize(string, options) ⇒ (width, height)
```

This is from the docs at http://effbot.org/imagingbook/imagedraw.htm.  So, you can get the width of the string "12," in pixels.  Now you can just subtract the width from the desired end position to know where to start it.  Unfortunately PIL doesn't seem to give a way to position text except by specifying the upper left-hand corner, so for other anchors, you have to compute it yourself (so far as I know).

EDIT: 
I just looked at the Pillow docs at http://pillow.readthedocs.org/reference/ImageDraw.html#functions

The signature for the function given there is

> PIL.ImageDraw.Draw.text(xy, text, fill=None, font=None, anchor=None)

However, in the comments below the signature, "anchor" is not explained, so it may be only a planned future enhancement.  My own experience with the Pillow docs indicates that this is a real possibility.  Personally, I would try to look at the Pillow source and determine the status before converting from PIL to Pillow just for this.

Comment: thanks! yes this is exactly what I do right now. But I wondered if there is an easier way to do that .

Comment: @ xtlc I'm adding some comments to my original answer.

Comment: Hey, textsize always returns me a wrong set of values. If I measure one letter with counting pixels I get something like 47x 59, but textsize returns a 12 x 21 size. Is it maybe because I use the `ImageFont.truetype('pathtofont', fontsize)` call?

Comment: I've never used truetype, so I can't say.  This may be relevant https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/644

Comment: yes I think this is exactly my problem. They even said it got fixes with version 2.6, but so far it's still not working. I am not really eager to write that function myself :(

Comment: I think you ought to raise this as an issue on that pillow wiki. (BTW do you have pillow installed or are you still using PIL?)

Comment: pillow 2.9.0 is installed.

Comment: If you figure this out, please answer the question

Comment: No success so far, altough I even switched to an open format font. Maybe if I have time I will do more testing and investigate further. I have to say the issue is not a really new one: https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/pull/784

Answer (score 0):

For everyone struggling with PIL and anchors - the documentation has been updated. Pillow supports anchor placement nowadays.

Here is the documentation: https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/text-anchors.html

*In your specific example you could place one text element relative to the baseline and the other one in regards to the ascendent layer.*